# How to name css class like facebook or google

Tags: css, webpack, classname

I found that Facebook or Google named css classes like:

```
class="_3_s0 _1toe _3_s1 _3_s1"
```

So I want to known why they named as "_s0" ,..... and how to generate class name like that. Can webpack do this?
Thanks you!

Comment: Why do _you_ want to do stuff you don’t even know the reasoning for yet …?

Comment: Rules for class names: https://benfrain.com/when-and-where-you-can-use-numbers-in-id-and-class-names/ Since they can mostly be set to whatever you want, the reason behind it will only be known to the developer. All I know is class names starting with underscore are not supported by older browsers.

Comment: I guess you want to minify your css to reduce the file size. If you're serving your files gzipped, the gain would already be marginal. I wouldn't bother with it.
that said; webpack offers some plugins that will minify class names, IE https://github.com/vreshch/optimize-css-classnames-plugin

Comment: These are probably abbreviations or shorthand used in a minification process. If there's no reason to do this for your particular application, then don't do it. You would have to have a pretty unique use-case to _need_ to do this.

Comment: Thanks you, but I think if we use class name like "_1toe" the .css file have smaller size than "name_of_class". That's why they named it like that.

Comment: I guess there're some plugin for webpack can rename class name, but if we use template file .html and put class name in, so can Webpack rename this class name to be the same with our .css file?

Comment: This might not answer your question completely but [this slide/post](https://speakerdeck.com/vjeux/react-css-in-js?slide=11) explains how it is done at Facebook. *It was originally posted in [this quora answer](https://www.quora.com/How-do-Facebook-structure-their-CSS-class-names).* I hope it gives you at least the general idea about how it's done and the perception that you should only put effort into it when it's absolutely essential.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at [tailwind](https://www.tailwindcss.com).

Each class represents one property, this is a new way to build CSS.
By this, you can reduce drastically the file size.

And you can use [css_loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/) and transpile the class name to a shorter one, making it as smaller as possible.

Of course Facebook doesn't use tailwind, but it is the same concept.
And I don't know how, but facebook changes all classes names on every refresh, this I think is to make it more difficult to read by crawlers

Answer (score 0):

That can be accomplished by using [css-modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules). With webpack this can be done via [`css-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#modules)

Answer (score -3):

If you can add your class in there css the you can easily give the property to that class.

For Example:-

```
<div class="_3_s0 _1toe _3_s1 _3_s1 your-css-name">
</div>
```

Comment: You don't understand my question

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: That can be accomplished by using css-modules.